# innerHTML within another tag

Tags: javascript

I have a link:

```
<a id="nextBut" href="somelink" class="button"><span>Next Step</span></a>
```

And I can control the the `<span>Next step</span>` part with innerHTML but how could I leave the `<span>` alone and just change the 'Next step' part?

For example:

```
var NextButJar = document.getElementById('nextBut');
NextButJar.disabled = true;
NextButJar.style.opacity = .5;
NextButJar.span.innerHTML = 'Read all tabs to continue';
```

I also have:

```
NextButJar.onClick = handleClick;
function handleClick(){
    if (this.disabled == true) {
        alert("Please view all tabs first!");
        return;
    } else {
        alert("allowed to run");
    }
};
```

Which I can't seem to get working either...

UPDATE

```
NextButJar.addEvent("click", function() {
    if (this.disabled == true) {
        alert("Please view all tabs first!");
        return;
    }
});
```

Works in everything but Explorer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NextButJar.firstChild.innerHTML = "foo";
```

Will set the HTML in the first child element. If you might also have other content in the node, do something along the lines of

```
NextButJar.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML = "foo";
```

Comment: I think you meant `NextButJar.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML = "foo";`.  `innerText` or `textContent` would be more efficient, though.

Comment: @Andy: Forgot the property... added it now. `innerText`/`textContent` introduce a browser incompatibility and I didn't want to go into that. Personally I infact tend to do `.firstChild.nodeValue` (provided that there is already some text in there), because that works in all browsers.

Comment: agreed, `innerHTML` is sometimes easier for simplicity.  It's just not a good idea in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

To use innerHTML give id to the span and change ite innerHTML

```
<a id="nextBut" href="somelink" class="button"><span id="nextButSpan">Next Step</span></a>
```